# Using open file dialog within gEdit using keyboard only

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, cinnamon, gedit, dialog

I use the default *gEdit* on Cinnamon on Linux Mint, but I find when opening files from within it, I cannot navigate the open file dialog solely using the keyboard.
I hasn't been intuitive how I use <kbd>tab</kbd> and direction <kbd>Keys</kbd>

My config for curious readers in the future:

```
cat /etc/linuxmint/info
RELEASE=17.2
CODENAME=rafaela
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rafaela_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rafaela_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=help:linuxmint
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

Virtual Machine Host:

```
uname -a
Linux ZOXFLI-FQXGR32 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I host the above from within a Oracle Virtual Box VM running on Windows 7 (SP1). I do not have any known file conflicts from within the VM that are inhibiting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate up and down the current file path location.

I haven't quite got this next part exactly correct, but if I want to navigate files within the selected path I can press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> usually. Sometimes its a bit unexpected doing this and I use different direction keys or combinations with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key until I get what I'm after. I will update once I have it down pat.